# Finding next element of a specific class inside a parent jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
<div class="container">
Test 1
<div class="child">Testing</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
Test 2
<div class="child">Testing</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
Test 3
<div class="child">Testing</div>
</div>
```

I wish to have the child div inside the container thats hovered over to show and hide when the mouse has left the container.

I do currently have:

```
        $('.container').hover(
            function () {
                $(this).next('.child').show();
            },
            function () {
                $(this).next('.child').hide();
            }
        );
```

However it does not seem to work.
Any advice appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use find() instead of next as it is a child element and not a sibling one:

```
    $('.container').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).find('.child').show();
        },
        function () {
            $(this).find('.child').hide();
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

next() is for siblings, you should use children for children :)...

```
 $('.container').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).children('.child').show();
        },
        function () {
            $(this).children('.child').hide();
        }
    );
```